# cursor.moveToFirst never returns true

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to search the MediaStore and so far I have had no luck in doing so.

Here is what my current code looks like:

```
    Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(uri, 
                    null, 
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + "=?", 
                    new String[]{songToPlay}, 
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC"); 

            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{  String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));

                 test.setText(path);
                }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }
```

songToPlay, uri are all correctly set.

the if statement is never executed.

What could cause this?

Comment: The cursor's probably empty. What is uri, songToPlay, etc?

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that [the cursor is empty](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29). Try out [`cursor.getCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29), and double-check if your query is correct. Are you sure the media store is populated? Do you have permissions to access it?

It looks like you are building search functionality, by the way. If this is true, be sure to use the LIKE operator, or better yet, [use full text search](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchingYourData).